# popup showing in a flutter project at the opening of any app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, popup

I want to show some popups in a fluttter project to get location and disable battery optimazation whenever I open the app.

I tried and showed this popup using ElevatedButton. But as I want to show this popup at the opening of the app, so this work using elevated button is not appropriate for me. So, is it possible to show popup from the first second without using any elevated button or something else? If it is possiblem, then please guide me how to do this.

Comment: Please clarify what it is that you want to achieve, how it should look like and what you have tried (with code snippets). Without these, it will be very hard for someone to help you out.

Comment: @tomerpacific Actually, I want to show a popup screen to get location access at the time of starting the app from the user for the smooth performance of the app.

Answer (score 0):

In an app of mine, I show a privacy-related dialog this way:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: [...],
        body: FutureBuilder(
              future: [...]
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  [..]
                      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
                        showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                            scrollable: true,
                            title: Text('privacy'),
                            content: Text(Constants.LEGALESE),
                            actions: [...],
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                    }
                    [...rest of the build method...]
              })
```

You can adjust the `Duration`: in my case, it usually happens too fast for the user to do anything else.